# Compare and insert from multiple tables?

Tags: php, mysql, database

There are 4 tables `table1,table2,table3` and `table4`

```
table1 has got 60000 datas
table2 has got 85000 datas
table3 has got 78000 datas
table4 has got 68000 datas
```

indexes on all tables are same but one got less than or more than each other. for example name `john` is stored in all 4 tables.but `mathew` is stored in may be two tables but not in other two and `ethan` may be stored in 3 tables but not may be in 4th one.

upto say first 60k all index/names are same but after that it is irregular

so how can I merge all these table into 1 table?? all four tables got 2 columns each and first one is name and second is its details

Answer (score 1):

There are probably more efficient ways of doing this, but this was the first thing that came to mind.

```
INSERT INTO table5
SELECT DISTINCT Table5Content.* FROM (
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table3
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table4
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table5
) as Table5Content
```

Comment: getting error #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @aron n : the alias I added in Chuck's query should solve this problem.

Comment: Oops! Thanks for having my back Greg. :)

Comment: what I need to mention after as??

Comment: @Chuck: you're welcome!
@aron n: Whatever you want, pwet, toto, michel, whatever... it is just an alias for the subquery which is built, so that you can refer to it in the upper select (using whatver.* instead of *, for example)

Comment: @aron, I updated the answer to hopefully shed some light on how it's being used.